# Can't print on standard output after using shmat

Tags: c, unix, output, shared-memory, fgets

So in this code `puts` can't display the output.

If I remove the `fgets` line, it prints `lola` but if I try to read and write on `shm`, nothing happens. How can I solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define SHMSZ 4096

int
main()
{
  pid_t pid1, pid2, pid3;
  pid1 = fork();
  if (pid1 == 0)
    {
      /* child1 */
      int shmid;
      key_t key;
      char * shm;
      key = 5678;
      if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
        {
          perror("shmget");
          exit(1);
        }
      if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1)
        {
          perror("shmat");
          exit(1);
        }
      printf("alright");
      if (fgets(shm,60,stdin))
        {
          /* This doesn't print. */
          puts(shm);
        }
      else
        {
          printf("hurara");
        }
      printf("lola");
    }
  else
    {
      pid2 = fork();
      if(pid2 == 0)
        {
          /* child2 */
        }
      else
        {
          pid3 = fork();
          if (pid3 == 0)
            {
              /* child3 */
            }
          else
            {
              /* parent */
              wait(0);
              wait(0);
              wait(0);
            }   
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it like any another string pointer? Thats why I used fgets here. Can you suggest something here. I need to store string data in shared memory so that other processes can access that.

Comment: @5gon12eder oops, i misread it as `fgetc()`

Comment: @umläute Can you suggest the error?

Comment: @SagarGrover Can you determine whether the `fgets` call succeeded?  If it fails, what is `errno`?  If all output fails, maybe communicate failure / success via the exit code.  Or try running through a debugger.

Comment: @5gon12eder It succeeds and their is no error. But puts is not printing anything, neither the next printf.

Comment: And `SHMSZ >= 60`, I assume?

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas then.  If you upgrade your question to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can compile and run, I can try offering more debugging help.  But with the information at hand, I frankly don't know.

Comment: @SagarGrover you are properly piping something into your progs `stdin`? because when i do,  it seems to work

Comment: @5gon12eder http://ideone.com/1xupQL

Comment: If u can please see it, I am dead stuck. I might rewrite the code, if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some problems with your `#include`s.  Did you compile with warnings on?  If I use these (issues annotated), the program compiles clean and behaves as I assume you expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
/* #include <sys/sem.h> */    /* this one is not needed... */
#include <sys/shm.h>          /* ...but this one is */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>         /* was missing, needed for wait() */
#include <unistd.h>           /* was missing, needed for fork() */
```

Comment: I didn't compile that way. Thanks a lot.